# Right click on button and Save PDF file As

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

There is a link behind button with PDF file on web page that I would like to access. PDF link has API key and can't be accessed directly. Button has ID `company_report_link`.

If I do `reportDownloadButton.Click();` PDF gets opened in separate tab of browser but I can't figure out how to download it.

I have tried right click the button and select Save As? I am able to open Chrome Context menu with this one, but can't select Save link As..

```
            // click the link to download
            var reportDownloadButton = driver.FindElementById("company_report_link");
            // reportDownloadButton.Click();

            // if clicking does not work, get href attribute and call GoToUrl() -- this may trigger download
            // var href = reportDownloadButton.GetAttribute("href");
            // driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(href);

            InputSimulator s = new InputSimulator();

            Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
            action1.ContextClick(reportDownloadButton);
            s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.DOWN);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
```

I have tried to do the trick with WebClient

```
var reportDownloadButton = driver.FindElementById("company_report_link");
var text = reportDownloadButton.GetAttribute("href");
// driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

WebClient client = new WebClient();
// Save the file to desktop for debugging
var desktop = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string fileName = desktop + "\\myfile.pdf";
client.DownloadFile(text, fileName);
```

but it does not work because of API. Web site is giving:

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.'

[image]

Comment: It should work with the `WebClient` approach, but you need to specify the API key in the request header or request parameters.

Comment: @NicodeOry any hint how to do that?

Comment: I can't advise any better without knowing about the web API service you're trying to use. How do you authenticate in the API?

Comment: There is no possibility to download it via API link directly. I am logging in, navigating through the website and getting on to the page with PDF link. API key seems to be the same all the time at least for different sessions I have tried to open yesterday. I have tested that I can access direct link (printing it to the console) before `client.DownloadFile(text, fileName);` but it does not work. I have also tested this method on other site without API and it works there.

Comment: You could try using a browser driver such as Selenium and autonomously navigate and download the file.

Comment: Yes, I did it with Selenium. Had to disable Chrome preview for PDF. Now it works